# Build failed issue on Android project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

when I build my app it shows this error message:

```
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.util.ClientCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: show your code then only we will able help you.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: At project Build .Its showing java compiler error and showing error Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.util.ClientCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException